# Getting correct frame size for UITableView(Controller) within UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I am using a UISplitViewController, where the Master View has two levels of hierarchy. Each node in the Master View has its own Detail View Controller, which I get from the storyboard like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    UIViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
    if ([vc isKindOfClass:[MKTableViewController class]]) {
        MKTableViewController *mkVC = (MKTableViewController*) vc;
        mkVC.mkController = self.mkController;
        if ([vc isMemberOfClass:[ForumTableViewController class]]) {
            mkVC.detailViewController = [self switchToDetailViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DiscussionTableViewController"];
        }
        if ([vc isMemberOfClass:[UserTableViewController class]]) {
            mkVC.detailViewController = [self switchToDetailViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UserViewController"];
        }
        if ([vc isMemberOfClass:[GroupTableViewController class]]) {
            mkVC.detailViewController = [self switchToDetailViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GroupViewController"];
        }
    }
}

- (UIViewController*) switchToDetailViewControllerWithIdentifier:(NSString*)identifier {
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard;
    storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPad" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController* vc = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];
    UINavigationController *navCon = self.splitViewController.viewControllers[1];
    UIViewController* detailViewController = navCon.viewControllers[0];
    for (UIViewController *child in detailViewController.childViewControllers) {
        [child willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
        [child.view removeFromSuperview];
        [child removeFromParentViewController];
    }
    [detailViewController addChildViewController:vc];
    [detailViewController.view addSubview:vc.view];
    [vc didMoveToParentViewController:detailViewController];
    return vc;
}
```

This all works, but the frame settings do not match. If I print the frame sizes of the different views, I get this:

- Size of SplitViewController.view: X:768.0 Y:1024.0
- MasterNavigationViewController.view: X:320.0 Y:768.0
- Size of DetailNavigationViewController: X:703.0 Y:768.0
- Size of DiscussionViewController: X:768.0 Y:1024.0

If I manually set the size of the DiscussionViewController.view using the following statement, it looks OK, but somehow I have to arbitrarily subtract 20 from the height. This feels wrong... What would be the correct way of doing this? The size of the DiscussionViewController is set to 'inferred', is there a way to have the view.frame automatically set correct when moving it to the Detail Navigation Controller?

```
    frame.size.height = detailNavController.view.frame.size.height - detailNavController.navigationBar.frame.size.height - 20.0;
```

(The Detail Navigation Bar Controller has a Navigation Bar and no Toolbar)

Version Information:

- iPad App for iOS7
- Xcode 5.1.1

Comment: What about the status bar, since its height is 20 ? (At least at iPhone, I'm not exactly sure if that's identical for iPad).

Comment: Good point, it is probably the status bar. But is there a way to automatically handle the frame size when moving the view to the Navigation Bar Controller? I experimented with `pushViewController: animated:`, but this didn't quite work out. After all, I do not have a stack of view controllers in my detail view. I just want different view controllers depending on the selection in the master view...

Comment: I think you should use modals instead of pushing. I'm not sure about automatically handling, but instead of adding subviews, if you use models for presenting view controllers, it will probably work as you want.